# MySQL query from PHP combining data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a follow system on my page and I need to show users only posts from users that they follow. I have a table in mysql named `follow` which contains `user1_id` and `user2_id`. If the user with id 34 is following the user with id 45, it is stored in that table. So what I need is Select all user ids that someone follows and find their posts from another table.
I need some commands that will `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE u_id=[users id-s that they follow].`
I already try something like this:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$follow_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_two_id FROM follow WHERE user_one_id=$id");
while($follow_array = mysql_fetch_array($follow_query)){

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT home FROM `matches` WHERE `u_id` IN (' . implode(',',array_map('intval', $follow_array)) . ')');
$sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($sql);}
```

but its not working.

This is the follow table:

[image: follow table]

It's showing that user 33 is following user 34 and user 35.

This is the table where the data that I need to show is stored:

[image: other table]

But I need to show a user only posts from users that he is following, in this case from users with id 34 and 35.

Comment: dump implode(',',array_map('intval', $follow_array)) so we know the values - also what's the error if any

Comment: isn't `$follow_query` false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should regroup your 2 queries with a `JOIN` in order to leave the processing to MySQL.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$offset = ($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

$query = sprintf("SELECT home, u_id FROM matches m
    JOIN follow f ON m.u_id = f.user_two_id
    WHERE f.user_one_id = '%d'
    AND m.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    ORDER BY m_id DESC
    LIMIT %d,%d", $id, $offset, $itemsPerPage);

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query : ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query:  : ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['home'];
    echo $row['u_id'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Can i somehow add WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) order by m_id DESC ?

Comment: thanks, i think this will work ... just one more question .. can i include $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; ...   I think this will look like this:    $query = sprintf("SELECT home, u_id FROM matches m
    JOIN follow f ON m.u_id = f.user_two_id
    WHERE f.user_one_id = '%d'
    AND m.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    ORDER BY m_id DESC" $limit, $id);

Comment: I edited again, to show you that you can add as many parameters as you want to the sprintf function. See also [the PHP documentation for this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
#select ID of users who are following a particular user
$follow_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_two_id FROM follow WHERE user_one_id='{$id}'");
#create an array in which we will contain "home" of users
$homes = array();
while($follower_id = mysql_fetch_array($follow_query)){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT home FROM matches WHERE u_id='{$follower_id}'");
    while ($home = mysql_fetch_array($follow_query)){
        $homes[] = $home;
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Put {} around PHP variables when pass to query.
- Home of users who are following first user is now in array homes.

Answer (score 0):

$follow_array is, as you named it, an array. You actually want to access to $follow_array['user_two_id']